# AWS Amplify breaks binary posts to AWS API-Gateway

Tags: react-native, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I'm creating a web application using React / Aws Amplify as the front end and AWS API-Gateway and S3 in the back end and Cognito as our user authentication. I have a page where the user needs to submit a form and a file. I was able to set this up for text files but once I started to work on binary files bad things happened.

I build the API in AWS and tested it using Postman as well as Curl and I'm able to post binary files. When I make the call through Amplify it stops working. I can make the call through Axios but then I need to turn off the Authentication, hence why I'm trying to do this through amplify. I also do not want to use amplify storage as it does not meet my needs. What typically happens is the file size is larger then the file sent and when I download it out of S3 it does not work any longer.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Dashboard.css";
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Home extends Component {
  uploadLambda = async (event) => {
    //This one work if I turn off User Authentication

    let file = event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    reader.onload = async () => {

      try
      {
        return axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'https://XXXXXXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/upload',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
          },
          data: reader.result
        }); 
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }

  uploadImageLambda = async(event) => {
    //This is the one I'm trying to get to work with binary files
    var file_name = event.target.files[0].name;
    console.log('Saving File Via Lambda: ' + file_name);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    //reader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]);
    //reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

    reader.onload = async () =>
    {
      try
      {
        /**
        Someone suggested this but it does not fix the problem
        let encoded = reader.result.toString().replace(/^data:(.*,)?/, '');
        if ((encoded.length % 4) > 0) {
          encoded += '='.repeat(4 - (encoded.length % 4));
        }
        console.log(encoded);
        //"isBase64Encoded": "true",
        **/
        return await API.post("lambdadocshell", 'upload', { 'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', },  'body': reader.result });
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="FileTest">
          <h1>Upload A File</h1>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select File: <input type="file" onChange={this.uploadLambda} />
          </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the code above you can see 2 upload functions, both hit the same API-Gateway. uploadLambda works but only if authentication on the API-Gateway is turned off. uploadImageLambda does not work regardless of authentication. We do use the Amplify in a number of other pages to move JSON back and forth to the API without issues. You can also see commented code as we tried a number of different ways to get amplify to work.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with AWS support, they said that amplify apparently does a JSON.stringify to the data which then increases the length of the file. Currently there does not seem to be a workaround for this issue. As such they suggested that I use Axios to make the request to API Gateway. Hopefully this will be resolved in the future.